# como leer las vistas de base de datos en django

Tags: django, django-models

si me pueden ayudar, tengo una base de datos ya creada y lo quiero conectar con django para ello voy a extraer los modelos con python manage.py inspectdb > models.py pero las vistas que están creadas en la db las ignora.
como puedo extraer las vistas a mis modelos ?

si me pueden ayudar por favor, Saludos gracias

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: no has dicho nada